# If we travel at near the speed of light until the end of universe

Tags: time-dilation, big-rip

If we travel near to the speed of the light, clocks will run slow for us due to time dilation.

What happens if we travel fast enough, say let's 99.999999% and more of the light speed and the universe die,in big rip or any other end of the universe theories.

What will happen to our spaceship?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean 99.999999% the speed of light relative to, say, the Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation Frame? There is no such thing as absolute speed. No matter how fast you're going, the speed of light will remain constant (light beams will still pass you at the same speed).

Comment: See "Tau Zero, " by  Paul Anderson

Comment: @CarlWitthoft though note a few major errors with it, like the misconception of the Big Bang as an explosion within the universe, or assumption that it would end in a collapse. And of course, Bussard ramjets are far less useful, and can't reach relativistic speeds.

Comment: Its a thought experiment. Any speed that makes the clock inside the ship survives to 10 to power of 10 to the power of 10 years but still below to the speed of the light. I understand your answer below. The universe will se me as any other relativistic particle and my ship won't survive. Thanks. I thought that I will become the universe, since my time isnt over. It's not the case. Thanks

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff  You're no fun :-) .   I do agree it's more of a Fantasy than a "hard SciFi" story.

Answer (score 1):

Your spacecraft will get slowly ablated by the interstellar/intergalactic medium, which it will see as relativistic particle radiation. The faster you go, the more intense the radiation you see.

From the perspective of the universe, your ship is just an unusually dense pack of tightly collimated relativistic particles, just as subject to getting scattered and slowed by collisions as any of the other relativistic particles filling the universe. Since the end of the universe will involve this happening as the universe settles to thermodynamic equilibrium, your ship pretty much by definition won't survive.

Answer (score -3):

travelling at .999999999c requires enormous quantities of energy. the energy needed to accelerate to such a velocity would incinerate you and all vicinity matter.
Also, at .99999999c, time dilation would be 7000 hours (291 days) to observer for every hour the ship travels...and in one hour...not even Earth to Saturn

Comment: Well, remember the Lorentz contraction as well-- at that relative speed, distances shrink enormously.

Comment: The question is not about how much energy will take. The question is about what will happens to a spacecraft with or without human being inside after the universe ends in time.